# Why do we need transitivity of equivalence

Tags: c++, strict-weak-ordering

Most C++ STL algorithms API impose certain requirements on comparator functions like transitivity (see [Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) for details). The requirements are intuitively understandable except for the transitivity of equivalence (aka transitivity of incomparability):

- if `a` and `b` are equivalent (i.e. `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`) and `b` and `c` are equivalent (i.e. `!(b < c) && !(c < b)`) then `a` and `c` must be equivalent as well.

What is the intuition behind this requirement?

For the mathematically inclined: I do understand that transitivity of equivalence allows us to define a strict total order over equivalence classes but this does not add much to understanding...

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253081/discussion-on-question-by-yugr-why-do-we-need-transitivity-of-equivalence); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

If you drop the requirement, then you are only requiring a partial order.

This immediately has two issues that come to mind:

1. Incomparability is not an equivalence relation any more, so e.g. containers like `std::set` can't use it to determine equivalence of keys any more. This could of course be worked around by having them take an explicit equivalence relation as additional parameter as e.g. `std::unordered_set` does.
2. Finding a total order that extends a partial order is not possible efficiently. Suppose that in a set of `N` objects, all are incomparable except for object A and object B. You need to test worse case all pairs of elements in order to figure out that `A` and `B` need a particular order because incomparability of any two elements doesn't imply anything any more about comparison with other elements. So something like `std::sort` could not be specified to have `N*log(N)` worse case complexity. I also expect that it would generally make it impossible to implement `O(log(N))` operations required for e.g. `std::set`/`std::map`.

Answer (score 0):

*My own take on this question.*

All fast sorting algorithms rely on transitivity of equivalence. For example the main step of quicksort, partitioning algorithm, selects a pivot element and puts all lesser elements to the left and greater ones to the right of pivot:

```
  loop forever 
    // Move the left index to the right at least once and while the element at
    // the left index is less than the pivot
    do i := i + 1 while A[i] < pivot
    
    // Move the right index to the left at least once and while the element at
    // the right index is greater than the pivot
    do j := j - 1 while A[j] > pivot

    // If the indices crossed, return
    if i >= j then return j
    
    // Swap the elements at the left and right indices
    swap A[i] with A[j]
```

Equivalent elements will be positioned around pivot in unpredictable ways. If there are two elements `a` and `b` that are equivalent to `pivot` but not equivalent to each other (e.g. `a` < `b`) they may easily be arranged in wrong order (`b, a`) by the above algorithm.

Many other STL algorithms (e.g. `std::min` or `std::min_element`) do not rely on transitivity of equivalence at all and could have been specified to require just partial ordering. I suspect weak ordering is currently required for them to keep the language standard slightly simpler.